# handling GCM registration ID's for multiple devices, same user

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

this is a common situation that lot's of apps facing, but I'm straggling to understand how to implement:

let's say that my application is a social network with a current logged in user.
I'd like to send GCM messages to that user, for all of his devices that currently logged in with my app.

that's mean that my server holds for each user a list of all of his registration ID's - one for each of his devices.

**the problem:** how can I track uniquely each one of his devices?   [seems there is no reliable way to get specific device identifier](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

without storing registration id for each unique device - I don't see how can I manage it.

things get messy when user will uninstall/logout and acquire new registration id afterwards, that suppose to replace one of the existing known id's,  but which one of them??

things will get even more problematic if Id like to send message only to a specific device, and not all of them...

please help me understand what I missing, and what is the right way handling multiple devices registration id's for same user.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Yes the server saves all registration ids, what's the problem?

Comment: @XaverKapeller: that's mean that if the user logged out and re-login with same user and device 1000 times, then my server sends 999 redundant id's to google clould??

Comment: create a UUID for each device that registers with your server. You dont need to worry about device unique keys. Once you create a UUID save it to shared preferences and anytime the reg id changes for the user send that to the server with the saved UUID

Comment: @tyczj: but if the user will uninstall my application and re-install it lost's of times, then I'll create different UUID for each installation..

Comment: @TalKanel No, Google handles most of that. You only have to delete the redundant ones and insert the new ones if something changes. You really don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: that's exactly what I don't understand how to do:   how my server or client can understand what are the currently not relevant anymore id's

Comment: @TalKanel I am pretty sure google returns what ID's are not valid when you make a call so all you have to do is remove them

Comment: @TalKanel I am writing an answer just now demonstrating how to handle this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google handles pretty much all the hard work for you when working with GCM. And they provided a simple method to always keep the registration id up to date. There is an extra field on each message sent called `canonicalRegistrationId`. If there is an id in that field, than the registration id has changed and needs to be updated. This field exists on every message and every time you send one, you have to check that field. If there is a new `canonicalRegistrationId` then you should update the registrationId as soon as possible. The old one may continue to work for some time, but there is no telling when it becomes invalid.

For example in a Google App Engine backend the code which handles the changing registration ids would look something like this:

```
// We want to send a message to some devices
// Get registered devices and then loop through them
List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(10).list();
for(RegistrationRecord record : records) {

    // Send the message to one device
    Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 5);

    // If the messageId is not null, then the message has been sent successfully
    if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
        log.info("Message sent to " + record.getRegId());

        // Check for canonical message id
        // If it is not null, then the registrationId has changed
        String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
        if (canonicalRegId != null) {

            // The registrationId has changed! We need to update it in the database
            log.info("Registration Id changed for " + record.getRegId() + " updating to " + canonicalRegId);
            record.setRegId(canonicalRegId);
            ofy().save().entity(record).now();
        }
    } else {
        ... // Irrelevant error handling
    }
}
```

So what you have to do is pretty simple: Every time you send a message, check if there is a `canonicalRegistrationId`, if yes then update the old registrationId with the canonical one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I look at your code, and I seems to me that instead of saving on the record the canonicalRegId, it will be better to delete the record entirely (assuming I have new record each time the client notify me about new registrationId).  would it be right?

Comment: Well the code above just updates the registrationId for a device which is already registered, that's what you should do too.

Comment: but then you'll have potentially multiple RegistrationRecord's holding same registraion id.  right?

Comment: because if your "foreach" iteration see a record with cannontial id that actually the same as other record been generated when the client provided afer the previous record was created..

Comment: I don't understand. The registrationIds are unique. There is **no way** that there will ever be a duplicate, no matter when or how a device was registered or how many times the registrationId has changed. The registrationIds are generated and provided by Google, neither you nor anyone else has influence on their selection.

Comment: I understand that registration id is unique. I ment that the following scanrio can happen: 1)phone generates new registration id = [x], and sends this id to the server.  2)server creates RegistrationRecord that it registration id = [x].

Comment: 3) phone acquire from some reason new registration id = [y], and sends it to the server. 4)server stores new RegistationRecord that it registration id = [y].   5) the server iterate all registration records, and  when invoking the sender.send() method for regId [x] , it get in response canonicalRegId = [y]. 6) according to your code - server change this record registration id to [y].  now you'll have two records that holds regId = [y].  where do I wrong??

Comment: Why would you have two records? I don't get why you assume that. The old record is just updated. No new record is created.

Comment: @TalKanel is right, if registration ID has changed, then probably the client notified it to the server, which added it to the list. So, the solution in your code should be simply: delete old registration ID and add the new one **only if it doesn't exist yet**.

Comment: @XaverKapeller what TalKanel tried to explain is what I also encounter: User signs into app first time, server gets regId X. User uninstalls app, installs it again. User signs in again, this triggers another regId Y to be sent to the server. If you don't check at this point a deviceSn, then you actually have the same device but with 2 regIds. That's the problem. At this point you have regIds X and Y, you send messages to both, and only after that you receive the canonicalId for X which should be Y. At this point you should delete X and only Y remains. But the message was still sent twice...

Comment: @Andrew You mean that your app receives the same message twice?

Comment: Well yes. Like I said, after the user installs the app again, you get regId Y, which you also save beside the old X one, as you don't know it's the same device. So when you try to send a message A to all of user's devices, you basically send message A to X and Y. Then immediately you receive a canonicalId "Y" for X's ACK and a simple ACK for Y; at which point, indeed, you go ahead and delete X as you already have Y. And all future message will be sent only to Y. But the damage is already done, the first message you've sent has been received by both X and Y, which happen to be the same.

Comment: So in order to avoid having the first message being sent twice to X(Y), I would suggest also saving a device_sn column on the Devices table, besides the registration_id one. At every sign in, you check if you already have a device row for the user_id & device_sn. If so, then update it's registration_id column. This would be equivalent for the canonicalId sent by Google. But in this case, you would be sending the first message only to Y. And you won't be receiving any more canonicalIds, as you've already updated X accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew And that is exactly where your misconception starts. If one message can do any damage all then you are doing it wrong. You are not supposed to transfer data over GCM. You are not supposed to convey any state or information. GCM messages should just notify the app of something. You cannot rely on GCM messages arriving in any order, you cannot rely on them arriving at all. It can talk one hour for the message to reach the app or it can take half a second. GCM is by design unreliable.

Comment: @Andrew If you GCM message would contain messages along the lines of "hey webservice x has some new stuff for you" then you cannot do any damage with a GCM message. Android provides a lot of functionality to help you with that like `SyncAdapter`. In [**this chapter**](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunByMessage) it is explained how you can sync data with the `SyncAdapter` in response to a GCM message. If the GCM message would arrive twice, it would request the sync twice, but the data would still be only synced once.

Comment: @Andrew Don't do that. You are just trying to use GCM in a way it is not supposed to be used. And adding a column and keeping track of device serial numbers just to "fix: GCM should by itself tell you that it is a bad idea and they you must be doing something wrong. GCM is supposed to work exactly that. You have to write your app using GCM the way it is supposed to be used, not trying to "fix" it and make it behave in a way you like.

Comment: What misconception? What you've described is not a solution. You're not doing *anything* wrong if you send data on the downstream channel. You can send whatever you want, it has nothing to do with the problem I just described... Imagine you use Hangouts and receive a message twice (if it's not being handled on client side) because you would've reinstalled the app. That's just not acceptable. Stop moving the discussion into another direction. We're not debating *what* you should or shouldn't send on the downstream channel.

Comment: @Andrew You didn't seem to get my point. Hangouts does not send the texts with GCM. You are not supposed to do that. The GCM message received just says "there are new messages" and then hangouts calls a webservices and syncs the data. If you receive the message twice, you might in the worst case scenario sync the data twice, but that doesn't break anything. And I am just trying to explain to you that you cannot fix this. This is how GCM is supposed to work.

Comment: @Andrew And I am telling you now, if you go down that road and start send actual data with the GCM message then you are just going to run into a whole slew of problems.

Comment: Already been using the system for the past year. If you're managing issues like this that may appear, the system works just fine. So like I said, stop with the "You're holding it wrong" comments. The issue here is that your first message will be sent twice if you don't do something about it. The complete solution would be to add support for both canonicalId changes + duplicate messages check on client *and* a device_sn column on the server. If the device_sn check fails, then you've got the canonicalIds and the client check to fix it. Period.

Comment: @Andrew Well If you want to do that then go ahead, I am just saying. That is how GCM is supposed to work and it most certainly shouldn't require fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Google supports **device group messaging**. Refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#managing_device_groups

To handle multiple users you can create a group for that user and add the registration id to that group. To create a group send a request like the following to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification:

```
Content-Type:application/json Authorization:key=API_KEY project_id:SENDER_ID

{ "operation": "create", "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris", "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"] }
```

This API returns a notification key in response which you can store in your db and later use to send notifications to that group. Subsequently whenever user logs in to some other device you can get the `reg_id` of that device and add it to the group. To add a device with the registration ID 51 to `appUser-Chris`, you would send this request:

```
{ "operation": "add", "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris", "notification_key": "aUniqueKey", "registration_ids": ["51"] }
```

And when user logs out of the device you can remove the `reg_id` from the group.

Sending a notification to a group is same as sending notification to a registration id.

One issue I have observed here is if you fail to store the `notification_key` to your db while creating a group there is no way you can get it again. And a new group cannot be created for that same `notification_key_name` again. A workaround to this problem is choosing your `notification_key_name` wisely. So when you fail to store the `notification_key` and try again to create a group with the same `noitification_key_name`, you will get an error. In that case you can simply change the `notification_key_name` for that user and create a new group. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to get Device IMEI no and save it to your server with Registration id and when user ReRegister him self with other device then get Check IMEI Number Replace it with old one. Main thing  Rise now in old device check send IMEI no with message and IF IMEI no is Match then no issue otherwise block application.and inform user...

Thats it...

Comment: Is it possible for some Wi-Fi tablets to not have an IMEI?

Comment: @hanamj : yes it is possible.